# Best way to bulk-close putty windows

Tags: windows, ssh, putty

My putty windows are getting out of control. When a session times out, it displays an error message which prevents bulk closing putty from the taskbar. I have to sort alphabetical in task manager and get rid of them all or just leave scores of windows. Is there any way to disable this error or bulk close the windows another way? Please don't tell me to log out of every window as I'm looking for a solution to bulk close. I'm using Windows. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use a PuTTY wrapper like [WinSSHTerm](https://winsshterm.blogspot.com). It will automatically close the error message window, if the session times out. You can then reconnect or close all disconnected sessions.